# Dagger scopes in Android

Tags: java, android, dagger, square

Jake Wharton's talk at Devoxx 2013, Architecting Android Applications with Dagger, talked about creating a Dagger scope for logged in users only. This sort of thing sounds really clean, and I want to do this in my applications.

The code that was discussed in the talk was something along the lines of:

```
public class LoggedInActivity extends Activity {

    @Inject User user;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_logged_in);

        DaggerScopesApp app = (DaggerScopesApp) getApplication();
        app.getObjectGraph().plus(new UserModule("exampleusername")).inject(this);

        findViewById(R.id.do_something_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(LoggedInActivity.this, user.username + " : " +
                        user.someValue++, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However, if the injected User is scoped as a @Singleton, then its properties will disappear on config change (as the object graph is created in onCreate).

The solution is pretty simple, you can just do this "plus" operation once and store the new object graph somewhere else (maybe the application class), but I was wondering if this is a good approach? Can anyone from Square provide any insight into what you do in your applications? Do you just not have singleton objects in the "logged-in" graph?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The solution is pretty simple, you can just do this "plus" operation once and store the new object graph somewhere else (maybe the application class), but I was wondering if this is a good approach?

Yep. The logged-in graph's lifecycle needs to live as long as the user is logged in and the process is around. Since the activity's lifecycle is extremely short, this isn't a good place for it.

I used it as an example to ease people into the concept using something they are familiar with.

> Can anyone from Square can provide any insight into what you do in your applications?

All graphs that aren't tied to UI are managed by an `Application` class. Through this we are guaranteed that it's created once, created first, and only disappears if the process dies.

Anything UI-related (activity-scope graphs, fragment-scope graphs, etc.) is plussed on top of these as the UI comes and goes.

Comment: Do you have multiple ObjectGraphs in your custom Application class? Is there one singular ApplicationGraph that may or may not include the AuthModule depending on whether or not the user is authed? Or would you have 2 graphs in this case... an ApplicationGraph and AuthedGraph? If so, is this AuthedGroup essentially `ApplicationGraph.plus(new AuthModule())`?